# using bootstrap modal to to display POST results

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django, twitter-bootstrap

I have a the following view that works ok and displays the results just fine in the template.

```
def PTR(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PTRForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            results = data_groups.setup_ptr(cd)
            t = loader.get_template('ptr_records.html')
            c = RequestContext(request,  {'results': results})
            return HttpResponse(t.render(c))
    else:
        form = PTRForm()
    return render_to_response('ptr_form.html', {'form': form})
```

However, I'd prefer the results display in a bootstrap modal.  I'm sure I can figure it out if I new where to start. Should I do the following....  Add jQuery to the form and have jQuery/javascript handle the post and get the results to put in a modal that is defined on the form itself.  That is, the modal won't be displayed until success is returned to the AJAX call?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you should do that, use Ajax to call the server then return the data as json then use jquery and bootstrap to display the modal